# jQuery count classes inside closest specific class

Tags: jquery

I've had a look everywhere and tried a couple of things, I can't seem to work out how I can cont how many .option-row classes are inside the closest .dynamic class.

I want to run some code if there is only one class with the name .option-row inside the closest .dynamic class.

I'm running this code inside a click event, which is a button inside a .dynamic class.

This is my code that isn't working, if it's of any help:

```
if($(this).closest('.dynamic .option-row').length == 1) {

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.find()` with `.closest()` here:

```
if($(this).closest('.dynamic').find('.option-row').length == 1) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to find the closest `.dyanmic` element first using [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) then use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find all the `.option-row` descendants inside the `dynamic` element

```
if($(this).closest('.dynamic').find('.option-row').length == 1) {

}
```

In your case you are trying to find the closest `.option-row` element which is a descendant of `.dynamic` with respect to the `this` element.